# Is there any option to store AC voltage?

Tags: ac, storage

Almost every power plants produce Alternating current. It is not necessary that entire energy that they produced are consumed in real time. Does they have any option to store excess energy?

Comment: Man, if the solution were only as simple as an answer on EE.SE!

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand what you said.

Comment: @tollinjose - He means that if there was a really good solution to what you're asking, we would probably be able to solve a great portion of the energy crisis.

Comment: hope some really cool inventions will happen in the future.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> **Does they have any option to store excess energy?**

"Excess energy" is typically stored in pumped-water hydroelectric reservoirs. This is used for 99% of world bulk storage capacity and may be up to 87% efficient. [Ref](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumped-storage_hydroelectricity)

Balancing (and smoothing) supply and demand is one of the reasons for large-scale (national) power-grids.

Being able to rapidly increase or decrease supply is one of the reasons for using gas-powered and hydroelectric generators instead of wind/solar/tidal powered generators.

> **Is there any option to store AC voltage?**

That's a kinda strange way to think of things. You could write the AC voltage down on a piece of paper and store that. :-)

As you said, the storable output of power plants is energy, not voltage. Outside cryogenic research labs, this is done by converting the energy to some non-electrical form.

---

On a household scale, off-grid. I believe you'd typically store excess generator output (solar, wind) as chemical energy in a large, heavy and expensive bank of lead-acid batteries, or maybe as thermal energy (heat) in a large body of water. Obviously you'd have to rectify any AC to DC in the former case.

If your household is on-grid and has it's own (non-fossil fueled) generating capacity, you'd typically "store" your surplus in the grid. This can be financially super-efficient as some nations pay you more to deposit your energy than they charge you to withdraw it.

Comment: I know its strange thought. What I was looking for is some method to store AC out more efficiently.

Comment: @tollinjose: More efficiently than pumping water up a mountainside? Exactly how much power (in Watts) and time (in seconds) are we talking about?

Comment: Yes More efficiently than pumping water up a mountainside that is what I meant. in this case my reference is hydro power plants itself.

Comment: @tollinjose: If there was something better, I imagine it would  be used and well-known. [*Pumped storage is 
water pumped to a storage pool above the powerplant at a time 
when customer demand for energy is low ... The water is then allowed to flow back through the turbine-generators at times when demand is high"*](http://www.usbr.gov/power/edu/pamphlet.pdf). [*"The Electric Power Research Institute (EPRI) reports that PSH accounts for more than 99% of bulk storage capacity worldwide ... efficiency varies ... between 70% and 80%"*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumped-storage_hydroelectricity)

Answer (score 1):

The most effective way to store an AC energy is to rectify it and charge Li-Ion accumulators and then to convert it back to AC by electronic inverters.

The high efficiency is because of the high efficiency of the Li-Ion cells and the high efficiency of the switching mode inverters.

Unfortunately, this method has many other disadvantages. The main of them is that the Li-Ion accumulators are too expensive for the needed capacity.

[Some development](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beacon_Power) has been made about using a [flywheel energy storage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flywheel_energy_storage), but everything is still for low-to-middle powers.

Answer (score 0):

i belive by storing the kinetic energy become potential energy is the best option rather than stroing with batteries that turns it into DC, consider all those power loses

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. Please make sure, that your post really answers the question. OP seemed to ask for storage of energy without converting electrical energy into something different. Others already have given answers involving the common ways of storing energy by conversion. Make sure your answer adds more information. Please take care as well, that you don't post guessings. Try to find proof for your claims.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to store the energy from AC power and it has been used for many years.  Pneumatic machinery like pumps and impact wrenches require air pressure.  An AC electric driven compressor pressures up a holding tank to a certain pressure and shuts off.  The pneumatic machinery continues to run on that pressure until the set pressure for the holding tank gets to a set point and the ac driven compressor starts again. Rinse and repeat. Theoretically you could store energy to run a car using AC power this way. Anything can run on pneumatic energy, you just need to design the motor accordingly.  It's the same as a wind up toy where the spring stores the energy.  DC power is based on corrosion of materials and batteries run by corroding the inside of the battery so there is no such thing as an AC battery unless you consider a capacitor as an AC battery.  They only store power for a very short time though, like "minutes" as Chekhov said on Star Trek when estimating how long the planet Vulcan had before it blew up. :) When you start to use the power though, it only lasts seconds.